# Execute Nohup command with input

Tags: process, perl, nohup

In UNIX, I have a process that I want to run using nohup. However, this process will at some point wait at a prompt where I have to enter `yes` or `no` for it to continue. So far, in UNIX I have been doing the following:

```
nohup myprocess <<EOF
y
EOF
```

So I start the process 'myprocess' using nohup and pipe in a file with 'y' then close the file. The lines above are effectively three separate commands - i.e. I hit enter on the first line in UNIX, then I get a prompt where I enter 'y' and then press enter to then finally type 'EOF' and hit return again. So this works perfectly, but my problem is below.

I want to now execute this in Perl, but I am not sure how I can execute this command, as it is over three lines. I don't know if the following will work:

```
my $startprocess = `nohup myprocess <<EOF &
y
EOF
`
```

Comment: this should work the way it is written in the question (after the first edit made it a bit nonsensical)

Comment: @hop I really don't know what you're talking about, the first edit added a newline and formatted the shell parts as code so they would display properly. I changed virtually nothing, the original revision is [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/442027f1-1383-4b74-9304-9561ef41cbd2/view-source)

Comment: @Michael: you are right and i'm sorry. i misinterpreted the diff and thought, you had added the backticks. makes the question even more nonsensical: the example as given should work.

Comment: @hop The perl one? I assumed it didn't work without trying as I don't know perl, but I guess he said "I don't know if the following will work", so maybe it is fine; you should probably just answer that the given example works

Answer (score 20):

If you just want to write a single `y` to the stdin of the process, you can do this:

```
(echo y | nohup myprocess) &
```

If you want to keep writing `y` for every prompt that comes up, the coreutil `yes` exists for exactly this purpose -- it will keep writing whatever you tell it to to stdout. Its default is to output "y", so you can just:

```
(yes | nohup myprocess) &
```

but if you need something else you can pass it as an argument

Comment: +1: I haven't seen `yes` used in eons

Comment: Michael, thank you for your prompt reply. However, I think I've tried your suggestion whereby I echo Y into the process. When I've done this, the output always spills onto my terminal despite the fact that I've ensured an & is in my

Comment: The & doesn't prevent the process output to be written to console. It just starts it in the background.

Comment: how has this answer anything to do with the question?

Comment: @Riccardo I experimented a little, and I think you're right. Fixed, thanks

Comment: @hop Er. How does it not? Did I misunderstand something?